# Which distribution has this Statistic model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, linear-model

For my exam I was given this statistic model:

$Y_i$=u+(1+a$x_i$)∗$ϵ_i$

where 
$u$ is an unknown parameter with all real values, 
$a$ is an unknown parameter in with values between ]-1;1[, 
$e_i$ is iid and N(0,1) ,
$x_i$ is known numbers between ]-1,1[ ,

But what does it tell? Is $Y$ normally distributed? I know that $e$ depends on both $x_i$ and $Y$, so $x_i$ is endogen variable. But how do I find the density distribution for $Y$?

Answer (score 0):

Normal distribution is closed under affine transformations:
$$ Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \ \sigma^2) \quad \Rightarrow \quad cZ + d \sim \mathcal{N}(c \mu + d, \ c^2 \sigma^2), \quad \forall c, d \in \mathbb{R}. $$
So in your case we have ($\epsilon_i$ playing the role of $Z$ above):
$$ \mu = 0, \quad \sigma^2 = 1, \quad c = (1 + a x_i), \quad d = u, $$
and consequently the $Y_i$:s are independent (because the $\epsilon_i$:s are) and
$$ Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(u, \ (1 + a x_i)^2) .$$